# Angular 10 better way to have text inputs as radio buttons and validating them

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, angular-material, radio-group

I have a page that has a lot of check box fields that are like this:

```
    <div class="question">
      <div class="row">
        <h5 class="app">Cerner Clairvia</h5>
      </div>
      <mat-radio-group class="radio-group" (change)="onRadioChange(8, $event.value)">
        <mat-radio-button class="radio-item" value="Charge RN">Charge RN</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button class="radio-item" value="POE">POE</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button class="radio-item" value="View Only">View Only</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button class="radio-item" value="Administration">Administration <p class="required">(Supervisor, Manager, Director)</p></mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button class="radio-item" [value]="'Location: ' + clairviaLocation.value" [disabled]="!clairviaLocation.value"><input #clairviaLocation type="text" class="form-control" id="clairviaLocation" name="clairviaLocation" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" placeholder="Enter location..."/></mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
    </div>
```

When a radio group item is selected `onRadioChange` is called:

```
  onRadioChange(appID: number, applciation: string): void {
    // Add all applicationAccess objects to model
    console.log('appID: ', appID, 'application: ', applciation);
    // Don't add the value if it's blank
    if (applciation !== undefined) {
      this.model.applicationAccesses.push(new ApplicationsAccessModel().setModel(appID, applciation));
    }
    console.log(this.model);
  }
```

The model item looks like this:

```
export class AccessRequestModel {
  requestorJhedId: string;
  requestorName: string;
  jhedId: string;
  fname: string;
  lname: string;
  department: string;
  title: string;
  managerJhedId: string;
  managerName: string;
  startDate: string;
  accessType: string;
  transferComments: string;
  endDate: string;
  dob: string;
  sponsoredManagerName: string;
  requestStatus: string;
  managerComments: string;
  submittedDate: string;
  userType: string;
  applicationAccesses: ApplicationsAccessModel[] = [];
  otherAccess: string;
}
```

But the only part we are worried about here is:

```
export class ApplicationsAccessModel {
  applicationId: number;
  accessDescription: string;
}
```

So in these radio groups whenever you select an item it adds the app ID that you selected and the description which is the value of the check box. These options appear like this:

[image]

Some of the groups are material select groups and look like this:

```
    <div class="question">
      <div class="row">
        <h5 class="app">Kronos Manager Setup</h5><p class="required" style="margin-left: 5px"><p class="required" style="margin-left: 5px">New Hires are automatically added to Kronos. Kronos Manager indicates the employee is to have access to ALL timecards and/or schedules in the cost center(s) specified.</p>
      </div>
      <mat-selection-list #kronosManager (selectionChange)="onApplicationSelection(19, $event.options)">
        <mat-list-option class="col-md-3" checkboxPosition="before" value="Time Cards">Time Cards</mat-list-option>
        <mat-list-option class="col-md-3" checkboxPosition="before" value="Schedules">Schedules</mat-list-option>
        <mat-list-option class="col-md-3 otherOption" checkboxPosition="before" [value]="costCenters31.value">Cost Centers <input #costCenters31 type="text" class="form-control other col-md-12" id="costCenters" name="costCenters" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" placeholder="Enter #..."/></mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
    </div>
```

```
  onApplicationSelection(appID: number, applciation: any): void {
    // Add all applicationAccess objects to model
    applciation.forEach(app => {
      // Don't add the value if it's blank
      if (app.value !== undefined) {
        this.model.applicationAccesses.push(new ApplicationsAccessModel().setModel(appID, app.value));
      }
    });
    console.log(this.model);
  }
```

To achieve the same goal.

My problem is with validating the text fields as select options. You'll notice that I have elected to not allow the options to be selected if nothing has been entered in the text field (radio group example), but I'm concerned that some users may just skip it if they can't figure out how to click it. If I remove the disabled feature then other problems arise.

I do validation in my own function on submit and I make sure that an error is thrown if any `accessDescription`  comes back under 2 characters. This means that either the field was left null or they just put 1 letter and moved on. This is in the validation method:

```
 for (let i of accessRequest.applicationAccesses) {
        let value = i.accessDescription.substring(i.accessDescription.indexOf(':') + 2);
        console.log(value);
        if (value.length < 2){
          validityCheck.isValid = false;
          validityCheck.reason = appMap.get(i.applicationId) + ': value must be 2 characters or more.';
        }
```

However, because the trigger for adding the selection is clicking the radio button if the user clicks the button THEN enters text the validation will still fail because at the time that ````onRadioChange``` was called the text field was null. This will be very confusing to the user.

To remedy that I have considered writing an asynchronous function that accepts the `appID` and `accessDescription` onTextChange and validating then, but I'm not sure that this is the best option.

I'm hoping for some advice on a clean way to do this. Perhaps there is a better way to structure my radio groups to include the text fields WITHOUT changing the models. I am very open to suggestions.

Comment: So if the user selects administration input should be disabled and vice versa?

Comment: No not at all... this question was specifically regarding the text field options...